# How do I swap CTRL and CAPS LOCK on Carbon Emacs on OSX without doing it OS-wide?

Tags: emacs, elisp, capslock

I've recently started learning emacs since I was unhappy with Textmate and as a starting point read the "Effective Emacs" article by Steve Yegge. I was very keen on his CTRL -> CAPS LOCK swap, but I don't want to do it OS-wide, I want this swap to only occur in emacs every time I run it.

I was wondering if there's a way to do this in the .emacs file instead of going into system-properties and swapping it for the whole OS. I'm using Mac OS X Leopard.

Comment: 'Fraid I don't have an answer for you, but...how often do you *use* caps lock? I mapped mine to control and have simply never missed it.

Comment: This also might be better on SuperUser.com...

Comment: @dmckee I'm sure one could do it using elisp though, which _might_ make it appropriate here, maybe...?

Comment: @bdonlan: That's why I'm wishy-washy on the matter. That and have to explain about finding the beta password...

Comment: Here's the password link, in case it comes to that: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/super-user-semi-private-beta-begins/

Answer (score 2):

This is, unfortunately, not possible to do in your .emacs file.

Comment: Especially if caps is hardware-controllered, as it used to be on the mac.